# SQL logical operator

Tags: sql, oracle

What are the occupations that are NOT student, lawyer or educator? List them in descending alphabetical order?

```
SELECT Occupation 
  FROM Viewer 
 WHERE occupation NOT IN 'student,lawyer,educator' 
ORDER BY occupation desc;
```

I keep getting an error. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IN` requires a list of expressions surrounded by parentheses:

```
SELECT Occupation
FROM Viewer
WHERE occupation NOT IN ('student','lawyer','educator')
ORDER BY occupation desc;
```

See the [documentation for `IN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm) to see the correct syntax:

[image: IN condition]